# How to ensure user input is alpha letters only using try and except

Tags: python

How can I ensure user input is alphabet letters only, and that the user is unable to continue until they have entered alphabet letters only? My below code picks up if user input is not alpha, but allows the user to continue anyway. What am I missing? Please help.

```
def inputdata(self):
    while True:
        try:
            self.name = input('\nEnter your full name:')
            if self.name.isalpha():
                print('Data is valid')
                # return self.name
                break
            else:
                raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
            print('Please enter letters only.')
            return False
```

Comment: Remove the ``return False``.

Comment: I've tried that, but still allows user to carry on without re-entering correct input

Comment: Why do you need a `try..except` when you have an `if..else` checking that the input `isalpha()`? Just add the `print()` in the `else:` block and get rid of the `try..except`. If you _must_ use `try..except`, then MisterMiyagi's suggestion should work. Note that spaces are not alphabets, so `"James Bond".isalpha()` would return `False` and cause your code to ask for input again.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion  with just the if..else - but its now it doesn't appear to 'see' the 'else' at all - and just accepts any input.  And then still allows the user to carry on.  As mentioned I've tried MisterMiyagi's suggestion to remove the 'return False' but to no avail

Comment: Expanding the code to a [mre] would be helpful, then. That includes providing some sample input for which the code fails.

Answer (score -1):

Remove statement `return False`, it means return from your function, not loop again.

It looks like there is still something wrong, like `Cancel` button, and `close` button of input window will break your script (`KeyboardInterrupt: Operation cancelled`)

Try this

```py
class Person():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.input_data()

    def input_data(self):
        while True:
            try:
                name = input("\nEnter you full name:")
                if name.isalpha():
                    print("Data is valid")
                    break
            except:
                pass
            print('Please enter letters only.')
        return name

person = Person()
print(person.name)
```

Comment: Why do you recommend a bare ``except:``? [This is an anti-pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) as it will suppress valid stop signals as well.

Comment: Yes, try to suppress all valid stop signals, only alphabetic string allowed, no cancel and no close window allowed.

Comment: But *why*? ``KeyboardInterrupt``, ``SystemExit``, and similar should *stop* an application completely, not be silently ignored.

Comment: Most of time, to break from script maybe not allowed for `users`.